# Should the “Convection Roast” setting be used for a prime rib roast?

Tags: meat, convection

Looking to cook a prime rib roast in my new convection oven. I understand that the “Convection Roast” setting alternates between the convection heating element and the broiler, and is designed for cooking meats. Is this the best setting for a Prime Rib Roast, however? Or should we use “Convection Bake?” My husband has a concern that Prime Rib is gentle and the direct heat from the broiler might be undesirable.

Everything on Google just talks about reducing the temperature by 25 °F, nothing talks about which setting to use... Should the “Convection Roast” or “Convection Bake” setting be used for a prime rib roast?

Answer (score 1):

That is quite doable. In fact it is common in restaurants that have a Hobart Convection Oven to do it this way.

The Hobart user manuals describe the procedure well. Here is one example:
http://kitchen.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/hobart_corp/hgc5x.html?p=19

And here is a recipe from an Australian catering company:
https://wursthauskitchen.com.au/recipes-inspiration/2020/9/4/cape-grim-standing-ribeye-roast

EDIT:
If you are concerned about heat from the top broiler, one good method to counteract it is to cover the roast with a tent/hood (if the roast is covered in mustard, then first place a sheet of baking paper over the meat, then form a cover using alfoil. the baking paper is to prevent the foil from touching the mustard/meat). The hood can be removed part way through cooking to allow the broiler element to further brown the roast if required.

Comment: You may want to clarify the first sentence - what is doable? Using the “Convection Roast” setting? The “Convection Bake” one? And if the detailed instructions were to be found within the answer (properly attributed, of course!), future readers wouldn’t be disappointed in case the existing links go bad, aka link rot, which is only too common on the Internet. Happy to answer any questions you may have about what should be in an answer and how to reference third party sources.

Comment: ‘Doable’ is a way of saying ‘possible’.  (No idea on ‘convection roast’ vs ‘convection bake’, as I have little experience with convection ovens)

Comment: reading further: doable because "it is common in restaurants that have a Hobart Convection Oven to do it this way" :)